# update query problem

Tags: php

hi all i have a field "ammount" in mysql database which have "varchar(50)" type. When i insert data into that field e.g ammount= 4 kg its ok but when i update that field it gives me the following error.

```
Error in query: UPDATE ingredients SET ingredient_name='test recipe',ammount=4 gm where ingredient_id='59'. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'gm where ingredient_id='59'' at line 1
```

and my query is

```
 $query="UPDATE ingredients SET ingredient_name='$ingredient',ammount=$ammount where ingredient_id='$ingredient_id'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The correct spelling is "amount".

2) **You should not be using variable interpolation like this for an SQL query. It is very unsafe**. Use a [prepared statement](http://www.google.ca/search?q=php+sql+prepared+statements).

3) You didn't put quotes around `$amount` when defining `$query`, so they don't end up in the final substituted query string. Look closely at the error message: it shows you the query that SQL tried to process. Notice how it says `ammount=4 gm`? It can't handle that, because there are no quotes.

If you [use prepared statements](http://www.google.ca/search?q=php+sql+prepared+statements) like you are supposed to, the quoting takes care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has:

```
...,ammount=4 gm where...
```

which is incorrect. You need quotes around `4 gm`.

Change

```
,ammount=$ammount where
```

to

```
,ammount='$ammount' where
```

Comment: It will "work", but please don't do this! If `$amount` comes from the user, he can set it to something like `'; DROP TABLE ingredients;--`, and he has erased your table.

Comment: How are you so sure `$ammount` is not sanitized before it's being used in the query?

Comment: "sanitization" is something that should never be attempted by hand, except insofar as you have specific requirements that the text match a specific pattern (e.g. <number in base ten><unit chosen from a list>). Even when you do, it doesn't hurt to do things properly. The library exists for a reason.